# React-native navigation with parameters issue, navigation uses StackNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am very confused about Stack Navigator as i have used the Argon theme for free and customized it, problem is when i navigate to any other screen i could not get parameter in that screen. please help me what am i doing wrong with my code, please check my handleNavigation method in **Home.js** also componendDidUpdate in **AddWord.js**, i tried dangerouslyGetParent().dangerouslyGetState() to get the params in my getParamsAndSetState() method in **AddWord.js** but it keeps the previous value even if i dont pass any object from navigation. basically i am passing id from home so addword is behaving as add/update component. files are here: 
**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, ScrollView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Block, theme } from 'galio-framework';
import { Card } from '../components';
import CustomCard from '../components/CustomCard';
import { argonTheme, tabs } from "../constants/";
import { Icon, Input } from "../components/";
import words from '../constants/words';
import articles from '../constants/articles';
import { withNavigationFocus } from '@react-navigation/compat';
import firebase from '../connection/Firebase';
const { width } = Dimensions.get('screen');

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [],
    search_text: '',
    navigationParams: {
      id: '',
      disabled: false
    },
    animating: true
  }
  getList = () => {
    firebase.firestore().collection('wordCollection').get().then(x => {
      this.state.items = [];
      x.docs.map(doc => {
        this.setState({
          items: [...this.state.items, {
            key: doc.data().key,
            word: doc.data().word,
            english_meaning: doc.data().english_meaning,
            arabic_meaning: doc.data().arabic_meaning,
            part_of_speech: doc.data().part_of_speech,
            synonym: doc.data().synonym
          }]
        });
      });
      this.setState({ animating: false });
    });
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({ animating: true }, () => {
      return this.getList();
    });

  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.isFocused && !prevProps.isFocused) {
      this.setState({ animating: true }, () => {
        return this.getList();
      });
    }
  }
  handleNavigation = (id, disabled) => {
    // i get the correct values here returned from my child component
    this.setState({ navigationParams: { id: id, disabled: disabled } }, () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('AddWord', this.state.navigationParams);
    });
  }
  renderArticles = () => {
    let myCard = this.state.items.map(value => {
      return <CustomCard customNavigation={this.handleNavigation} myItems={value} />
    })
    return (
      <ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.articles}>
        <Block style={{ paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE }}>
          <Input
            onChangeText={(w) => { this.setState({ search_text: w }) }}
            right
            placeholder="Search"
            iconContent={
              <Icon
                size={20}
                color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                name="search-zoom-in"
                family="ArgonExtra"
                onPress={() => { this.search() }}
              />
            }
          />
        </Block>
        <Block flex>
          {myCard}
        </Block>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const animating = this.state.animating;

    return (
      <Block flex center style={styles.home}>
        {animating == false ? this.renderArticles() : <ActivityIndicator animating={animating} size="large" style={styles.activityIndicator} />}
      </Block>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  activityIndicator: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 80
  },
  home: {
    width: width,
  },
  articles: {
    width: width - theme.SIZES.BASE * 2,
    paddingVertical: theme.SIZES.BASE,
  },
});

export default withNavigationFocus(Home);
```

**AddWord.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
// Galio components
import { Block, Text, Button as GaButton, theme } from "galio-framework";
// Argon themed components
import { argonTheme, tabs } from "../constants/";
import { Button, Select, Icon, Input, Header, Switch } from "../components/";
import firebase from '../connection/Firebase';
// import {NavigationEvents} from 'react-navigation';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';
import { withNavigation, withNavigationFocus } from '@react-navigation/compat';

const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");

class AddWord extends React.Component {
    state = {
        "switch-1": true,
        "switch-2": false,
        word: '',
        synonym: '',
        part_of_speech: '',
        english_meaning: '',
        arabic_meaning: '',
        params: {
            id: '',
            disabled: false
        },
        animating: true
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // this.dbRef = firebase.firestore().collection('wordCollection');
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.isFocused && !prevProps.isFocused) {
            const { navigation, route } = this.props;
            const itemId = route.params;
            //gets undefined
            console.log('showing item id', itemId);
            this.setState({ animating: true }, () => {
                this.getParamsAndSetState();
            });
        }
    }


    getParamsAndSetState = () => {
        const navigation = this.props.navigation;
        navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().dangerouslyGetState().routes.map(v => {
            if (v.params != null) {
                console.log("i am here to check if params are null or not", v.params);
                return this.getData(v.params.id).then(() => {
                    this.setState({ animating: false });
                });
            }
        })
    }
    getData = (id) => {
        let col = firebase.firestore().collection('wordCollection');
        col = col.where('word', '==', id);
        return col.get().then(x => {
            if (x.docs.length > 0) {
                this.setState({
                    word: x.docs[0].data().word,
                    english_meaning: x.docs[0].data().english_meaning,
                    arabic_meaning: x.docs[0].data().arabic_meaning,
                    part_of_speech: x.docs[0].data().part_of_speech,
                    synonym: x.docs[0].data().synonym
                });

            }
            else {
                this.setState({
                    word: '',
                    english_meaning: '',
                    arabic_meaning: '',
                    part_of_speech: '',
                    synonym: ''
                });
            }

        });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ animating: true }, () => {
            this.getParamsAndSetState();
        });

    }
    toggleSwitch = switchId =>
        this.setState({ [switchId]: !this.state[switchId] });

    addWord = () => {
        firebase.firestore().collection('wordCollection').doc(this.state.word).set({
            word: this.state.word,
            part_of_speech: this.state.part_of_speech,
            english_meaning: this.state.english_meaning,
            arabic_meaning: this.state.arabic_meaning,
            synonym: this.state.synonym
        }).then((data) => {
            //success callback
            console.log('data ', data)
        }).catch((error) => {
            //error callback
            console.log('error ', error)
        })
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        //this doesn't get called if i click home screen again
        this.setState({
            word: '',
            synonym: '',
            part_of_speech: '',
            english_meaning: '',
            arabic_meaning: '',
            params: {
                id: '',
                disabled: false
            }
        });
    }
    renderInputs = () => {
        const disabled = this.state.params.disabled;

        return (
            <Block flex style={styles.group}>
                <Block style={{ paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Input editable={disabled} value={this.state.word} onChangeText={(w) => { this.setState({ word: w }) }} style={styles.inputStyle} placeholder="Word" iconContent={<Block />} />
                </Block>
                <Block style={{ paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Select onSelect={(i, v) => { this.setState({ part_of_speech: v }) }} value={this.state.part_of_speech} style={styles.dropDown}
                        defaultIndex={0}
                        options={
                            ["Noun", "Pronoun", "Verb", "Adjective", "Adverb", "Preposition", "Conjunction", "Interjection"]
                        }
                    />
                </Block>
                <Block style={{ paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Input value={this.state.english_meaning} onChangeText={(w) => { this.setState({ english_meaning: w }) }} value={this.state.english_meaning} style={styles.textArea} placeholder="English Meaning" iconContent={<Block />} />
                </Block>
                <Block style={{ paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Input value={this.state.arabic_meaning} onChangeText={(w) => { this.setState({ arabic_meaning: w }) }} value={this.state.arabic_meaning} style={styles.textAreaArabic} placeholder="Arabic Meaning" iconContent={<Block />} />
                </Block>
                <Block style={{ paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Input value={this.state.synonym} onChangeText={(w) => { this.setState({ synonym: w }) }} value={this.state.synonym} style={styles.inputStyle} placeholder="Synonym" iconContent={<Block />} />
                </Block>
                <Block style={[{ paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE, alignItems: 'center' }]}>
                    <Button onPress={() => { this.addWord() }} color="success" style={styles.button}>
                        {disabled ? "Add" : "Save"}
                    </Button>
                </Block>
            </Block>
        );
    };
    render() {
        const animating = this.state.animating;
        return (
            <Block flex style={styles.customContainer}>
                {animating == false ? <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 30 }}>
                    {this.renderInputs()}
                </ScrollView>
                    : <ActivityIndicator animating={animating} size="large" style={styles.activityIndicator} />}

            </Block>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    dropDown: {
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: '80%',
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
    customContainer: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    textArea: {
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: '80%',
        height: 100
    },
    textAreaArabic: {
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: '80%',
        height: 100,
        textAlign: 'right',
    },
    inputStyle: {
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: '80%'
    },
    title: {
        paddingBottom: theme.SIZES.BASE,
        paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE * 2,
        marginTop: 44,
        color: argonTheme.COLORS.HEADER
    },
    group: {
        paddingTop: theme.SIZES.BASE * 2,
        width: '100%'
    },
    shadow: {
        shadowColor: "black",
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowRadius: 4,
        shadowOpacity: 0.2,
        elevation: 2
    },
    button: {
        marginBottom: theme.SIZES.BASE,
        width: width - theme.SIZES.BASE * 2
    },
    optionsButton: {
        width: "auto",
        height: 34,
        paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE,
        paddingVertical: 10
    },
    input: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1
    },
    inputDefault: {
        borderBottomColor: argonTheme.COLORS.PLACEHOLDER
    },
    inputTheme: {
        borderBottomColor: argonTheme.COLORS.PRIMARY
    },
    inputTheme: {
        borderBottomColor: argonTheme.COLORS.PRIMARY
    },
    inputInfo: {
        borderBottomColor: argonTheme.COLORS.INFO
    },
    inputSuccess: {
        borderBottomColor: argonTheme.COLORS.SUCCESS
    },
    inputWarning: {
        borderBottomColor: argonTheme.COLORS.WARNING
    },
    inputDanger: {
        borderBottomColor: argonTheme.COLORS.ERROR
    },
    social: {
        width: theme.SIZES.BASE * 3.5,
        height: theme.SIZES.BASE * 3.5,
        borderRadius: theme.SIZES.BASE * 1.75,
        justifyContent: "center"
    },
    activityIndicator: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 80
    }
});

export default withNavigationFocus(AddWord);
```